# PDO Limit characters returned?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible in PDO to limit the character return? I'm trying the following but it simply doesn't return a results set no matter which field I put in the LEFT, yet the rest of the query in this case the id and title is returned as expected. Am I missing something?

```
    $sql = "SELECT LEFT(content,10), id, title FROM posts";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
```

So I'm loading my model (above) via the controller like so:

```
    $posts_model = $this->loadModel('PostsModel');
    $posts = $posts_model->getAllPosts();
```

Then in my view Im echoing out the results like so:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><h3><?php if (isset($post->title)) echo $post->title; ?></h3></td>
    <td><?php if (isset($post->content)) echo $post->content; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Not sure if this helps any? Like I say I can switch title and content around and it will echo them out it just wont echo the column in the LEFT part of the SQL statement. I've tried the raw mysql query in PHPMYAdmin and it returns the data as I expect just wont work in the live application using PDO.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on one of the returned records, I'm assuming the key is different than you expect.

Comment: Show how do you output the rows,I suspect you need an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `SELECT LEFT(content,10)`, then the *column name* in the result set will be "LEFT(content,10)", so you'd need to access the data as `$post->{'LEFT(content,10)'}`. To avoid that, give it an alias:

```
SELECT LEFT(content,10) AS content ...
```

Comment: brilliant thank you, completely missed the obvious on this one... long day :(

Comment: It's often better to truncate in your application than at the database level. That way you can include an ellipsis if the content is truncated.

Comment: @tadman I was told it was better to do this database side as it saves time not returning result sets that are not needed?

Comment: You're saving a marginal amount of information here, maybe a few hundred characters per row at most. You also have no idea if the content was truncated or not, something that'll potentially confuse your users. Considering your database is probably connected by a gigabit-type link, it'd take millions of rows to make for a measurable difference here. The only exception to this is potentially huge `LONGTEXT` type columns.

Comment: @twigg This is a situation where you have to way cost vs. cost. Yes, it uses more resources to do the truncation in PHP vs. doing it in MySQL; but on the other hand doing it in PHP is easier development-wise and enables a little more freedom in what exactly you can do (or at least replicating the same things in MySQL, like ellipses for truncated text, would be more complicated than doing them in PHP). Likely you're not in a situation where there is a significant enough performance gain to sacrifice code simplicity for it. Decide for yourself.